# How to solve BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException

Tags: spring

I am writing a small application to check the functionality of "AfterAdvice" concept in spring-AOP but i am getting an exception related to xml file (I think) please help me how to solve the exception

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">
<bean id="pinCheck" class="com.nt.advice.AtmPinVerifierAdvice" />
<bean id="targetBean" class="com.nt.service.AtmPinGenerator" />
<bean id="pfb" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="target" ref="targetBean" />
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>pinCheck</value>
        </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

ClientApp.java

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;
import com.nt.service.AtmPinGenerator;
public class ClientApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //activate IOC container
    ApplicationContext ctx = new    FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("src/com/nt/cfgs/applicationContext.xml");
    //get proxy obj
    AtmPinGenerator gen = ctx.getBean("pfb",AtmPinGenerator.class);
    //call b.method
    gen.pinGenerator();
  }

}
```

AtmPinGenerator.java

```
import java.util.Random;
public class AtmPinGenerator extends Random {
//generating pin
public int pinGenerator(){
    //creat java.util.Random object 
    Random rad = new Random();
    //use nextInt() to generate random pin of 4 digits
    int pin = rad.nextInt(9999);
return pin;
  }//pinGenerator
}
```

AtmPinVerifierAdvice.java

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.springframework.aop.AfterReturningAdvice;
public class AtmPinVerifierAdvice implements AfterReturningAdvice {
@Override
public void afterReturning(Object retValue, Method method, Object[] args,
        Object target) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(retValue);
    Integer pin = (Integer)retValue;
    //if generated pin is less than four digit throw an exception
    if(pin<=999)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid pin");
  }//afterReturning
}//AtmPinVerifierAdvice
```

If I run the above application I am getting this Exception

Output

```
Aug 17, 2015 2:03:57 PM     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing     org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@3ff14318:     startup date [Mon Aug 17 14:03:57 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Aug 17, 2015 2:03:57 PM     org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader     loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from file     [G:\java\Frameworks\SpringAOP\AOPProj6(After advice - pin verifier     decl)\src\com\nt\cfgs\applicationContext.xml]
Exception in thread "main"     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named     'pfb' must be of type [com.nt.service.AtmPinGenerator], but was actually of type     [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2]
    at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(Abstract    BeanFactory.java:375)
at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBe    anFactory.java:199)
at     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractA    pplicationContext.java:962)
at test.ClientApp.main(ClientApp.java:14)
```

I don't why I am getting Exception. please any one help me why this exception is raising?

Comment: Force the use of class based proxies by configuring the `ProxyFactoryBean` as such. By default JDK Proxies are used, and currently you get a proxy implementing only `Serializable` (which is implemented by `Random`). To fix enable class based proxies or slap another interface on it `PinGenerator` for instance containing the method you are needing and then program to that interface instead of the concrete class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring by default uses JDK Dynamic proxies, which are interface based, for applying AOP.

Your `AtmPinGenerator` extends `Random` which implements `Serializable`. Spring sees the interface and uses interface based proxies. You will get a proxy implementing only the `Serializable` interface.

You have 3 options to solve it

1. Force class based proxies by configuring the `ProxyFactoryBean`
2. Create an interface and implement it
3. Force class based proxies by not extending `Random`.

The last option would be the easiest simply don't extend `Random`, this will force the use of class-based proxies.

```
public class AtmPinGenerator {

    public int pinGenerator(){
        Random rad = new Random();          
        return rad.nextInt(9999);
    }
}
```

You could also set the `proxyTargetClass` property of the `ProxyFactoryBean` to `true` and then you don't need to change your class.

```
<property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true" />
```

The last option is to introduce an interface and simply expose the `pinGenerator()` method on it and let your `AtmPinGenerator` implement that interface.

```
public interface PinGenerator {

    int pinGenerator();
}

public class AtmPinGenerator implements PinGenerator { ... }
```

This way you are using interface based proxied. In your `main` method now use the `PinGenerator` interface instead of the `AtmPinGenerator`.

Comment: thank you very much @M.Dinum your solutions are awesome I solved my problem by using your last approach. but i'll try with remaining approaches  to solve my problem without modifying class. thank you